# max or min per column by factor

Tags: r

I have a dataframe A with n columns. I need to find max value (but not 0 when other values are less than 0) per column by factor B.

dataframe(A)

```
B   a    b
1   0    0
2   0    0
3   0    0
1  -0.1 0.1
2   0.2-0.3
3   0   1
1  -0.3 0.4
2  -0.5 0.2
3   0.1 0.2
```

The output im looking for looks like this

```
B  a     b
1  -0.3  0.4
2  0.2   0.2
3  0.1   1
```

I know that i can use `aggregate` function but it only works for one column at a time.
The algorithm for each column is:
1. neglect all 0
2. if all values<0 then take the min of the values, else take the max

Comment: You can use an `*apply` function to use aggregate on all columns ?

Comment: Yes, but it takes 0 as max value when two others are negative. But in this case i need to take the max negative value

Comment: But for group 1 you take `-0.3`. Shouldn't it be `-0.1`?

Comment: @Sotos, sorry i expressed wrongly the desired output, it should include the lowest/highest value among three

Comment: ... and if all values for a particular grouping value are 0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution with base R:

```
f1 <- function(x) { x1 <- x[x!=0]; if(all(x1<0)) min(x1) else max(x1) }
aggregate(cbind(a,b) ~ B, data=A, FUN=f1)
```

*(The function `f1()` is taken from the answer of @akrun)*
result:

```
#> aggregate(cbind(a,b) ~ B, data=A, FUN=f1)
#  B    a   b
#1 1 -0.3 0.4
#2 2  0.2 0.2
#3 3  0.1 1.0
```

data:

```
A <- structure(list(B = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), a = c(0, 
0, 0, -0.1, 0.2, 0, -0.3, -0.5, 0.1), b = c(0, 0, 0, 0.1, -0.3, 
 1, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2)), .Names = c("B", "a", "b"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Answer (score 4):

We can try with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
f1 <- function(x) {x1 <- x[x!=0];
                   if(all(x1<0)) min(x1) else max(x1)}
setDT(A)[, lapply(.SD, f1), by = B]
#   B    a   b
#1: 1 -0.3 0.4
#2: 2  0.2 0.2
#3: 3  0.1 1.0
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
A %>% 
    group_by(B) %>% 
    summarise_each(funs(f1))
# A tibble: 3 × 3
#      B     a     b
#   <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1  -0.3   0.4
#2     2   0.2   0.2
#3     3   0.1   1.0
```

#### data

```
A <- structure(list(B = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), a = c(0, 
0, 0, -0.1, 0.2, 0, -0.3, -0.5, 0.1), b = c(0, 0, 0, 0.1, -0.3, 
 1, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2)), .Names = c("B", "a", "b"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: Thank you  @akrun, it give an error  `missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

Comment: @ThePooh  I am not finding any error with your example data.  Updated with the data I used